# Facebook Submitting App Review for Page Public Content Access

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

recently I am trying to learn how to extract comments of facebook posts of public page via Facebook Graph API, e.g extracting comments of CNN's Facebook posts.

due to the recent change to Facebook API, it seems like I will need to submit an App Review in order to extract data from public page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS
because I've been getting the below message when using the graph api:

> "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this 
>   endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public 
>   Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable 
>   features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review."

however, it is also stated that "You do not need to submit your app if it will only be used by you or by a reduced number of people.": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit

my question is do I need to submit app review since I am only using it for my own learning purpose. or is there a way to go around this since submitting an app review is a bit overkill because I will need to provide things like Privacy Policy URL, Terms of Service URL and screencast etc which I do not have.

Comment: If you’re just doing it for learning purposes, then that should work fine using any pages you own/have admin access to. (If you don’t have any, you can create one.)

Comment: @CBroe I also intend to perform text analytics on the content scrapped thus creating my own page does not fully meet my goal.

Comment: _“I also intend to perform text analytics”_ - even more reason why this should be reviewed, before you are let lose on _my_ data that I might have posted on one of the public pages you intend to get your data from … // You want any data from a public page that you don’t own/have admin access to, then you need to submit your app for PPCA. Otherwise, you only have access to pages you do own/manage.

Answer (score -1):

- go to this link: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
- Create a new app
- Put a display name which you want to associate with this app id
- Go to settings > Basic
- Fill up all the details
- An app icon needs to be added
- A privacy policy needs to be added ( use this : https://termsfeed.com/privacy-policy/generator/ )
- Finally save changes

•   Now Go to the app review (1. Make your app public then 2. Start a submission)
•   Select the items you want to include in this submission
•   Currently I have submitted below items, if you want you may add
•   Click on add details ( preferably “Page public content Access)
•   And fill details for page public content access

[Click here to see attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohrpS.png)

Comment: What did you upload in the "Screencast requirements"?